# Why doesn't {a^nb^n | n >= 0} follow regular language closure properties?

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, dfa, nfa

Using the pumping lemma, we can prove that {a^nb^n | n >= 0}, but what is not clear is the following.

{a^n | n >= 0} is regular by itself and so is {b^n | n >= 0}, and if I am not mistaken, regular languages are closed under concatenation, so why doesn't {a^nb^n | n >= 0} follow this rule?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

The `n` in `{a^n | n >= 0}` is not the same as the `n` in `{b^n | n >= 0}`. After concatenating them you get `{a^jb^k | j,k >= 0}` that is regular. It is not the same as `{a^nb^n | n >= 0}` (or to say `{a^jb^k | j,k >= 0; j=k}`) where the repetitions of `a` and `b` are the same number.